# Install Monetdb alongside with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, monetdb, postgresql-9.5

I am not sure if it is the right place to ask but, will it cause problems if I install Monetdb on the ubuntu which already has postgres installed on it? I know it will fight for the system resources, but I mean if it will cause other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Monetdb and Postgres together without problems for testing purposes. There are no any problems.